# Reading and sorting from CSV file C++

Tags: c++

Hello guys so I need help on a project that reads from a .csv file into a dynamic 2d array or a vector. The CSV file contains details of a swimming competition where i am supposed to read both names times and distances for different distances and times. Then I am required to sort them using times and distances and a user should be able to search for a race based on distances and it should show him/her the fastest times for a certain distance.
Here is my code which doesn't sort values by time because it is still in string format despite my attempt to convert it to int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

bool sortByTime(const vector<int>& v1,const vector<int>& v2 );
int main(){
    vector< vector<string> > heatLevels;
    ifstream in("code.csv");
    if(!in)
        cout<< "File not found"<< endl;

    string line,sector;

    vector<string> v;

    while(getline(in,line)){
        v.clear();
        stringstream ss(line);
         while (getline(ss,sector,','))  // break line into comma delimited sectors
        {
            v.push_back(sector);  // add each sector to the 1D array
        }

        heatLevels.push_back(v);  // add the 1D array to the 2D array
    }

    for(int i = 0; i< heatLevels.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<heatLevels[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout<<heatLevels[i][j]<< setw(12);
        }
        cout<< "\n";
    }
    for(int i = 1; i< heatLevels.size(); i++)
    {
        int j=5;
        stringstream converter(heatLevels[i][j]);
        float x =0.0;
        converter >> x;

    }

    //Sort table by time
    sort(heatLevels.begin()+1, heatLevels.end(),sortByTime);


}
bool sortByTime(const vector<int>& a,const vector<int>& b )
{
    return a[5] < b[5];
}
```

Comment: That's because you have a vector of strings, and a vector of vectors of strings. Perhaps what you're looking for us [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)?

Comment: Is your problem in reading the `CSV` file or just sorting the results?

Comment: The way to approach this is to declare a POD (plain data) struct for the records, then go through the CSV converting each row into a struct and putting them into a vector, then call std::sort on the vector.

Comment: I don't understand.  A search of "StackOverflow C++ read file CSV" will produce a plethora of examples.  I don't understand why people don't search first or use a debugger.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have already searched for it on Stack Overflow none of them are similar to mine

Comment: @Galik The problem is sorting

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean 's comment is the right way to do this. I would declare a `struct` to store each record (line) from your `csv` file. Then you can sort them using the standard `std::sort()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to `int` or `double` at the time of sort. You can also use lambda functions to make this easier:

```
int main() 
{
    vector<vector<string>> heatLevels;
    ifstream in("code.csv");
    if(!in)
        cout << "File not found" << endl;

    string line, sector;
    while(getline(in, line)) 
    {
        vector<string> v;
        stringstream ss(line);
        while(getline(ss, sector, ',')) 
            v.push_back(sector);  
        heatLevels.push_back(v); 
    }

    for(auto &row : heatLevels)
    {
        for(auto &e : row)
            cout << e << ",";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    auto sortproc = [](const vector<string> &a, const vector<string> & b)
    {
        double ia, ib;
        try
        {
            ia = std::stod(a[5]);
            ib = std::stod(b[5]);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            cout << "invalid or out of range\n";
            return false;
        }
        return ia < ib;
    };

    std::sort(heatLevels.begin(), heatLevels.end(), sortproc);

    cout << "sorted:\n";
    for(auto &row : heatLevels)
    {
        for(auto &e : row)
            cout << e << ",";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Above method is fast enough, but it's not the most efficient way because you make a lot of `string` -> `int` conversions. As suggested in comments, you can use a structure instead.

Comment: Is this while still reading from a .csv file because I am totally lost

Comment: I don't know what you mean. See the edit. If it doesn't work then show sample data (content of input file code.csv) and show your output.

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack Overflow, just seen it the complete implementation using the vectors. How would you do it with structs?